# Addition of spin?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

There is something I don't fully understand. When I have a problem like this: Let's look at a system with $j_1=1$ and $j_2=2$ spins. Let our system be in the state in which the total spin is $2$ and the projection onto the $z$ axis is 0 ($S_z$). What values can the $S_z$ of the $1st$ particle take?

When I have a problem like this, I always start by creating this fig:[image]

It represents the eigenstates. It's easy, I just have to find the simpliest way to the $(J=2,M=0)$.

But when the problem is that I just have to add, for example, 1/2 and 1/2 spins, then how can I find the eigenstates? There must be a basic formula for it, I've been looking for it but I can't find it.

Answer (score 2):

You have $-j_1 \leq m_1 \leq j_1$, where $m_1$ has the same nature as $j_1$ (integer or semi-integer), and idem for $j_2$ and  $m_2$. Now you have $M = m_1+m_2$. It is easy to see that the only possibilies for $m_1, m_2$, in your case ($M=0, j_1=2, j_2=1$), are $(-1,1), (0,0), (1,-1)$. Now to see the exact decomposition in these states, you must understand [Clebsch–Gordan coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients#Formal_definition_of_Clebsch.E2.80.93Gordan_coefficients), and their recursion relation. For the exact decomposition, see for instance the array [$j_1=2, j_2=1$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients#j1.3D2.2C_j2.3D1), for $m=0$, and $j=2$